# How to set up the Twilio iOS SDK to connect to the server and make phone call?

Tags: ios, swift, twilio, callkit

I am new to iOS development, and trying to use `Twilio` to deliver a voice conference application. I followed the documentation to setup the example from https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-ios, and I successfully made a few phone calls to the `Twilio` Bin.

However, when I try to migrate it to my own application, it somehow doesn't work. I copied the `Server` folder and setup the `.env` accordingly, and dialed a call. I saw my phone enter the status of calling, but it doesn't connect to any phone call. I checked my source code and noticed that it was the `callDidConnect` function in `CallDelegate` wasn't triggered. Therefore my phone hung on the "dialing" but never connected to any phone call. And I didn't see any network activity anyhow.

Here are my questions:

1. Do I need the `Server` folder to actually dial a phone call?
2. How does iOS client connect to any server, either `Twilio` or my own `Nodejs` server? I dont' see a line that is doing it.
3. Where do I put my `API_SID_KEY`, `AUTH_TOKEN` ...etc if I want to build my own server?
4. Could anyone provide an example repository of using `Twilio` to make phone call?
5. I already had some knowledge in `CallKit`, how is `CallKit` integrated

I am attaching my source code below, they are simply prototype, I have simplified  to help me to figure out how it works:

When user clicks the dial button, it calls this function:

```
 func performVoiceCall(uuid: UUID, client: String?, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    let connectOptions = ConnectOptions(accessToken: accessToken) { builder in
        builder.params = [self.twimlParamTo: ""]
        builder.uuid = uuid
    }

    let call = TwilioVoiceSDK.connect(options: connectOptions, delegate: self)
    callKitCompletionCallback = completionHandler
}
```

then this function will be triggered by above function and with success

```
 func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXStartCallAction) {
    provider.reportOutgoingCall(with: action.callUUID, startedConnectingAt: Date())

    performVoiceCall(uuid: action.callUUID, client: "") { success in
        if success {
            NSLog("performVoiceCall() successfully")
            provider.reportOutgoingCall(with: action.callUUID, connectedAt: Date())
        } else {
            NSLog("performVoiceCall() failed")
        }
    }

    action.fulfill()
}
```

Eventually I expected the following functions will be triggered, BUT IT DOES NOT:

```
extension RoomPageViewModel: CallDelegate {
func callDidConnect(call: Call) {
    print("Call did connect")
}

func callDidFailToConnect(call: Call, error: Error) {
    print("Call did fail to connect", error.localizedDescription)
}

func callDidDisconnect(call: Call, error: Error?) {
    print("Call did disconnect")
    }
}
```

I believe the biggest problem is that I don't understand how the client actually communicates with either `Twilio` or my `NodeJS`, therefore I don't know why the `callDidConnect` function is not triggered

Comment: have u resolved this issue?